# Выбор элемента при нажатии на него Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, button, ui

Как сделать так что бы при нажатии на кнопку(лого) было видно какой элемент выбран(изменение фона) и при нажатии на другую кнопку(лого) предыдущая кнопка становилась не активной. что то вроде переключателя только с большим количеством кнопок. Спасибо!

[image: Список кнопок]

[image: Иерархия]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделай List в скрипте доступный с инспектора. Перетяни в инспектор все кнопки.

При нажатии на любую кнопку обращайся к скрипту и отключай подсвечивание всех остальных кнопок с этого скрипта. А потом врубай подсвечивание на нажатой.